# magento 2 luma theme - container names

Tags: luma-theme

There are some containers in Luma theme, how can I get their names?

I want to move the container that has the search bar below the container that has the main menu. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it.

`<move element="top.search" destination="content" before="-" />`

For finding containers you have to look through layout xml files; they are in the respective Magento modules and theme overrides.

Magento 2 has a utility in the backend for blocks goto:

`Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Debug`

from here you'll have options of:

- Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront
- Add Block Names to Hints

do that it and you'll get some insight about blocks and where to look.

Comment: Thanks a lot. On destination content, I got the search box on the cms page (if that makes sense). However, on getting the "top.search" got a few interesting links. Finally added a custom container and am happily styling at the moment. Regards.